# Services manager that lets me copy service name?

Tags: windows-7, windows, services

services.msc and programs I've tried lack an essential feature - ability to copy service name in order to Google it. Do you know a proper services manager?

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I copy the service name when using `services.msc`?

- Select a Service
- Right click and select "Properties"
- The "Service name" will be highlighted

  [image]
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the name to the clipboard.